# A heart for stable equivariant homotopy theory

Tags: stable-homotopy, equivariant-homotopy, reference-request

Let $G$ be a finite group. I wonder whether the following statement is true, known and written down:

There is a t-structure on the stable $G$-equivariant homotopy category such that the associated heart is isomorphic to the category of Mackey functors (on $B_G$).

I feel like someone has told me so, but I can't find a reference. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you define "t-structure" and "heart"?  

Comment: @Dev: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulated_category#t-structures I am pretty sure that the answer to your question is "yes", with truncation functors given by connective covers, but my references aren't handy.

Comment: The answer is certainly "yes," but the only proof I know off the top of m head is that you first show that the homotopy category of G-equivariant spectra is equivalent to the homotopy category of "spectral Mackey functors," where the t-structure is easy to write down. (In fact this is an equivalence of infty-categories; I'm still writing up these details.) Presumably there's a more direct proof; I seem to remember some appendix of Gaunce Lewis ... Sorry I can't be of more help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since G is finite, there is no problem with just repeating the proof in the 
case $G=e$, using $Z$-graded homotopy group functors on the orbit category. Take
$D^{\leq n}$ to be the spectra whose homotopy groups $\pi_q(X^H)$ are zero for $q>n$, 
and dually for $D^{\geq n}$.  The intersection for $n\leq 0$ and $n\geq 0$ consists 
of the Eilenberg-MacLane $G$-spectra $K(M,0)$ for Mackey functors $M$.

Peter May

Comment: Sorry, can you explan why the couple $(D^{\le 0}, D^{\ge 0})$ yields a t-structure? Surely, abstract nonsense yields the existence of a t-structure whose non-negative part is precisely $D^{\ge 0}$; should one apply some "standard topological argument" to compute $D^{\le 0}$ then?

Comment: The proof is identical as for $G=e$, once you understand $G$-CW spectra, for which the source is http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/BOOKS/equi.pdf. The point is that they satisfy the same formal properties used in a standard proof for $G=e$. I can add full details, but I hope that is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you! I am currently reading some texts on equivariant spectra including your book; yet this requires some time. As about formal properties: I am interested in an equivariant version of the vanishing of negative stable homotopy groups of spheres; cf. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/245006/where-can-i-find-basic-computations-of-equivariant-stable-homotopy-groups

Comment: Ok, since I thought I had already answered this question, I've gone back and answered your other question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/245006/where-can-i-find-basic-computations-of-equivariant-stable-homotopy-groups.  The negative homotopy groups of any suspension $G$-spectrum are zero.  My long answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/65180/why-are-equivariant-homotopy-groups-not-rog-graded?rq=1 is also relevant.